# Append a file or command at the end of the line of another file

Tags: shell-script

I've been trying to do this for hours now,

I have a file that have this data, let's call it data1:

```
test1,test2,test3
```

I want to add a count, along with a comma to the end of the line of this data.
Let's assume that I'm counting the number of lines of data1 , which is 1 line.

```
echo ", $(wc -l < data1 | bc)"
```

I want my output to be:

```
test1,test2,test3,1
```

I've tried echo, printf, some awk( I still don't get this much), cat.

Answer (score 1):

With awk

```
awk '{$0=$0","NR}1' data1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a POSIX file, `echo "$(head -c-1 data1)","$(wc -l <data1)"` will output what you want. `head` removes the trailing newline.

Answer (score 0):

Use sed to append the number to the last line:

```
STRING=`echo "$(wc -l < data1 | bc)"` && sed -i '$s/^\(.*\)$/\1,'"$STRING"'/' data1
$ cat data1 
test1,test2,test3,1
```

First part saves the number of lines to the variable `STRING` and the sed takes the last line and appends the `,` and content of `$STRING` variable to the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

The `paste` command is used to add columns:

```
$ wc -l <data1 | paste -d, file -
test1,test2,test3,       1
```

This is *literally* what you asked for; the output of `wc` is added to the end of the line of the file.  The output of `wc` has whitespace at the start of the line, which is why you get the spacing you get here.

To remove this whitespace:

```
$ wc -l <data1 | sed 's/^ *//' | paste -d, file -
test1,test2,test3,1
```

---

The `paste` command is here used with `-d,` which makes it insert a comma between the old and the new columns.  The `-` signals that the new columns should be read from standard input rather than from a file.  The standard input comes from `wc -l` which counts the number of lines in the file.

The variation with `sed` simply takes the `wc` output and removes any space characters at the start of the line.

---

Using `bash` process substitution:

```
paste -d, file <( wc -l <data1 | sed 's/^ *//' )
```

Here, the process substitution, `<( ... )`, takes the place of `-`.